# Solution of Linear Electrical Circuit

Tags: electric-circuits

We learned in class that the number of independent KCL equations is N-1(N-number of nodes) and the number of independent KVL equations is B-(N-1) (B- number of branches). Thus we have B independent equations and we can solve the circuit for the currents. What I don't understand is how can we know for sure that the B equations are independent? The union of two independent sets of vectors is not necessarily also independent.

Answer (score 1):

The KVL and KCL equations alone are **not** sufficient to solve a circuit.

You also need to include an equation describing the I-V relationship of each circuit element, called the *constituent relations* for the circuit elements.

If this weren't true, any two elements in parallel would produce the same voltages and currents, regardless if one is a power source and the other resistor, or both are resistors; and regardless of the values of the power sources or resistors.

Once you include the constituent relations, these plus either the N-1 KCL equations *or* the B-(N-1) KVL equations are sufficient to find all node voltages and branch currents in a linear circuit.

Comment: How do we know the equations are sufficient? Maybe there aren't any solutions?

Comment: If the constitutive relations are linear and time independent then the Kirchhoff equations form a system of linear differential equations with constant coefficients and their solution is unique and can be had by any number of  methods, e.g., Laplace Transform.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the proof off the top of my head, but it's a fundamental result in circuit theory that the node equations are independent, and therefore sufficient to solve the network. [Nagel's Tech Report](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1975/ERL-520.pdf) on the original SPICE simulator may be helpful reading but I don't see a proof of this particular theorem included there.

Comment: A Circuit Theory textbook like Chua, Desoer, and Kuh will certainly include the proof you're looking for.